# How can I select with a GroupBy into an anonymous class with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list:

```
public static List<PhraseSource> phraseSources;
```

The list has property:

```
public int? JishoJlpt     { get; set; }
```

I am trying to get a count of the number of how many of each number of JishJlpt occur:

```
phraseSources.GroupBy(p => p.JishoJlpt)
             .Select(g => new {
                JishoJlpt g.Key,
                Count: g.Count()
             });
```

But it's giving me this error:

[image]

Can anyone help and give me advice on what might be wrong?

Comment: That's just metadata about the method - what _actual_ error are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a syntax error. Anonymous objects use `=` instead of `:`

This works for me:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(1);
list.Add(3);

var items = list.GroupBy(p => p)
    .Select(g => new {
        Key = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count()
    });
```